# C program crash when I do a big memory allocation on the stack

Tags: c, windows, memory, tabs, allocation

This simple program crash when I compile and run it on Windows with Visual C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    printf("function begin\n");
    int n[1000000];
    for(long int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        n[i] = 2;
    }
    printf("function end\n");
}
int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    foo();
    printf("end of the program\n");
}
```

I compile with `cl bug.c`.

In this case, the console only displays:

```
C:\Users\senss\Desktop>bug
hello
```

However, when I change the 1 000 000 value to 100 000, there is no problem :

```
C:\Users\senss\Desktop>bug
hello
function begin
function end
end of the program
```

Thank you!

Comment: The stack is a limited resource. On Windows the default process tack is only a single MiB.

Comment: Change `int n[1000000];` to `int *n = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(int)); if (!n) return;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! [Pun intended] :)

Comment: Thanks you for your help and your explanations I'm going to fix it !

Answer (score 1):

The default stack on Windows is [1MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/thread-stack-size)

`int n[1000000]` is 4bytes * 1000000 = 4MB, so it crashes. 
When you change it to 100000, it's 400K so it's OK.

In practice I think you may want to allocate large array in heap instead of stack to avoid stack overflow.

```
int* a = new int[1000000];
...
delete [] a;
```

or in pure C

```
int* a = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(int));
...
free(a);
```

If you don't like pointers, consider using a std [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) to make things easier.

Comment: The tag is C, not C++.